# Refer "sudo pip" to anaconda pip

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) installed in my ubuntu system.

If I use `sudo pip` in terminal, it seems that it refers to system pip, not to anaconda pip. I run `sudo which pip` to verify it.

The `sudo which pip` gave me output of `/usr/local/bin/pip`,
and `which pip` gave me the output of `/home/ubuntuUser/anaconda3/bin/pip`

How to change the configuration so that when I use `sudo pip`, it refers to my anaconda pip

Answer (score 3):

Which instance of `pip` is used when you type `pip` is determined by the contents of your `$PATH` environment variable.  Your environment variables are normally replaced - as a security measure - by `sudo`.   You can change this so as to keep your existing `$PATH` value, unless `sudo` has been configured not to let you.  From the [`sudo` manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

> -E The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment
>   variables. The security policy may return an error if the -E option is
>   specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the
>   environment.

As anaconda is only available in your environment (and not root's) you need to pass `-E` to sudo.

Comment: Sir，I am in the Anaconda envs where I can use `pip install`. But when I use `sudo -E pip install`, the error `sudo: pip: command not found` still occurs. How should I solve this. I need to install `keyboard` with root, thanks!